# Web request not repeating after failure, try/catch not working

Tags: vb.net, web, timeout, webrequest

I am trying to send a web request to a Snom PA1 bell.  The bell rings periodically throughout the day, but occasionally times out trying to contact the bell.  That would be fine, but after this happens a couple times, the web request stops sending altogether.  the sub still runs, but no bells.  Also, while debugging, the webrequest throws a webexception that is not handled by the catch, even though it is contained within the try/catch.

Does anyone know why the web request would stop working after a failure?

```
Private Sub ringIPBell(ByVal params() As Object, Optional ByVal secondattempt As Boolean = False)

    Dim IPaddress As String = params(0)
    Dim ringSeconds As Double = params(1)
    Dim wr As Net.HttpWebRequest

    If ringSeconds = 2 Then
        wr = Net.HttpWebRequest.Create("http://" & IPaddress & "/line_login.htm?l=2")
    Else
        wr = Net.HttpWebRequest.Create("http://" & IPaddress & "/line_login.htm?l=1")
    End If
    wr.Method = "post"
    wr.CachePolicy = New System.Net.Cache.RequestCachePolicy(System.Net.Cache.RequestCacheLevel.NoCacheNoStore) 'added Oct2010
    wr.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("correctName", "correctPassword")

    Dim postdata As String = "PLAY_RINGER:1=Play Ringer"

    wr.ContentLength = postdata.Length + 2
    Dim requestStream As IO.Stream, strmwrit As IO.StreamWriter
    Try

        requestStream = wr.GetRequestStream()
        strmwrit = New IO.StreamWriter(requestStream)
        strmwrit.WriteLine(postdata)
        strmwrit.Close()
        Dim responsestream As New IO.StreamReader(wr.GetResponse.GetResponseStream)


        Catch ex As System.Net.WebException
        If Not secondattempt Then
            ringIPBell(params, True)
        End If
        Dim testvar As String = ex.ToString
    Catch ex As Exception
        Beep()
    End Try
```

Also, I previously had the following code ringing the bell, but it would only work for one of the two bells, Even though as far as i can tell their settings were identical.

```
requestStream = wr.GetRequestStream()
strmwrit = New IO.StreamWriter(requestStream)
strmwrit.WriteLine(postdata)
strmwrit.Close()
requestStream.Close()
```

As suggested I broke out the responestream line as such:

```
requestStream = wr.GetRequestStream()
            strmwrit = New IO.StreamWriter(requestStream)
            strmwrit.WriteLine(postdata)
            strmwrit.Close()
```

it breaks on "requestStream = wr.GetRequestStream()"

with the error:

"A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll 
Additional information: The operation has timed out"

Comment: Would it make sense to break out the initialization and assignment of the responseStream object into several steps so you can catch whether the exception is being generated there?

Comment: that it would.  I'll change that, and if anything becomes apparent I'll post it.